# Android Beginner - Wrapping and PlainText - Eclipse/AndroidStudio

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

Hello guys I am currently learning how to make apps and I encountered few problems I am trying to do the same thing in both Eclipse and AndroidStudio and I am having 2 different problems with PlainText fields..

in Android Studio: The field height is too big even thought I've set it to "wrap_content" I'm including an image - http://prikachi.com/images/110/7455110m.png how can I make it to really wrap the content inside I don't want the field to be bigger than the number

in Eclipse: whenever I try to add Plain Text field I get an error - http://prikachi.com/images/113/7455113A.png

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".crazy_tip_calc">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/bill_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/billTextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/billEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/billEditText"
    android:ems="5"
    android:text="@string/bill_edit_text"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/billTextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean `TextView`? Also post your xml.

Comment: I have added the code, and I am talking about the EditText field, if you look at it in the screenshot, you will see that the field height is nearly 2 times bigger than the number inside it, I don't want it to be that big

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the textview is using the defailt height of the normal text and is aligned to the top left corner which is default.

To achieve what you want, put those `TextView` and `EditText` in a `LinearLayout` and set the `android:gravity` to `center_vertical`. To change the height of the `TextView`, use `android:textSize` attribute

or set `android:textAppearance` to `"?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"` or `"?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"`

Comment: Hello, thanks, but I don't want to make the text bigger, I want to make the EditText field smaller, it's height is almost twice as much as the number inside it, I want it to really wrap its content and not be 2 times bigegr..

Comment: That is the default size of the edittext. If you try to make it smaller, its looks will distort and it won't look good..

Comment: And it is actually wrapping the contents. The contents in a the edittext include the boundies and padding also.

Comment: Okay what about the error in eclipse, it just doesnt let me add EditText field